# Как избавиться от повторяющихся элементов в массиве массивов?

Tags: php

Коллеги!

Не знает ли кто-нибудь, как можно удалить массивы-дубли в массиве массивов, то есть устранить элементы, у которых повторяются и ключ, и значение, и значение значения... Попробовал вот это для приведенного ниже примера:

```
$test = array_unique_key($test, 'id'); 
print_r($test);
```

но он удаляет и те элементы, в которых ключи одинаковы, но некоторые значения различаются. Просто `array_unique` дает результат только с двумерными массивами...

```
$test = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 5000,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 5000,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 6342,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала следует обратить внимание на то, что в одном массиве не могут существовать два элемента с одним ключом. Так что `array_unique_key` просто не имеет смысла. Получается, что вас интересуют именно повторяющиеся значения (хотя бы эти значения и массивы). Идём на php.net/array_unique, читаем... и обнаруживаем интересный атрибут $flags!

```php
$test = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 5000,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 5000,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Диски Sparco',
        'price' => 6342,
    ),
);
var_dump(array_unique($test, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Вжух!

Comment: Большое спасибо, что объяснили! Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
$uniqueDecodedItems = array_unique(array_map('json_encode', $array));
$result = array_map('json_decode', $uniqueDecodedItems, [true]);
```

Или в одну строку:

```
$result = array_map('json_decode', array_unique(array_map('json_encode', $array)), [true]);
```

На выходе:

```
//------------------------------
// Output:
//------------------------------

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Диски Sparco
            [price] => 5000
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Диски Sparco
            [price] => 6342
        )
)
```

Comment: Но можно так же сделать и по-людски, используя один цикл, а не 100500

Comment: @Ипатьев кто как хочет, тот так и....танцует.